# Why I have to manually active my GPUs?

Tags: cuda

I installed a new Intel Xeon Phi in a work station which already has 3 Nvidia GPUs installed. To make the Phi card work, I have to load the Intel's MIC kernel module into my Linux kernel. And by doing so the Phi card works fine. However, every time when we reboot the system, we just couldn't use the GPU. The error message is that the system couldn't find the CUDA driver.

However, the only thing I need to do to fix this is to use "SUDO" to run one CUDA binaries or some Nvidia's command just like "sudo nvida-smi". Then everything just works fine, both CUDA and Intel's Xeon phi.

Anybody knows why? Without my sudo command, other people just can not use the GPUs. This is kind of annoying. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please report the GPU and motherboard spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CUDA requires that certain resource files be established for GPU usage, and this is covered in the Linux [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#runfile-installation) (step 6 under runfile installation -- note the recommended startup script).

You may also be interested in [this article](http://www.resultsovercoffee.com/2011/01/cuda-in-runlevel-3.html), which focuses on the same subject -- how to automatically establish the resource files at startup.

Once these files are established correctly, an ordinary user (non-root) will be able to use the GPUs without any other intervention.

I have no idea why Xeon Phi installation might have affected this in your particular setup.